# Create Procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `msgbackup`()
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO messenger_backup SELECT * FROM messenger;
END
```

Table messenger: id, client_id, admin_id, messenger, ref_id, status, timestamp.

How to retrieve data > 7 days messenger_backup copy table . As the data in 7 days, still retained in the table messenger.
Example: If the data in the table is 10 days, the messenger will take 3 days of data copy to messenger_backup table .

Comment: Hope you are maintaining the messenger_dateTime and storing the time of message receiving so that you can later run a query to find date based on date filters.

Comment: yes i will do it. tks you :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7` for select old data

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `msgbackup`()
BEGIN
INSERT INTO messenger_backup
Select * From messengerWHERE timestamp < DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
END
```

Comment: sorry but what's p1.dErstellt?

Comment: can i use timestamp < DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY ?

Answer (score 0):

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `msgbackup`()
BEGIN
INSERT INTO messenger_backup
Select * From messengerWHERE timestamp < DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
END